# docker-compose volumes not working this way

Tags: docker-compose, docker-registry, volumes

in my docker-compose.yml , I am using the registry:2  image  ( version) 
as I need to set up my own configuration ( for using S3 storage ) , I tried to mound my config directory in place of the default one

/usr/share/docker-registry/config/config.yml  # my own registry config in local host
/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/cmd/registry/config.yml  # default in container

in my docker-compose.yml , I wrote

```
backend: 
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 
  links: 
    - cache 
  volumes:
    - /usr/share/docker-registry/config:/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/cmd/registry
 ..
```

but when I compose it, my config settings are never taken in account... it's always using the default settings in the container cmd/registry/config.yml

what could be wrong ?

If I inspect the running registry:v2 container , I can see that

thanks for any enlightenment ...

If I inspect the running registry:v2 container , the config is weird ( S3 info are there, but no volumes , and the CMD is executing the standard config.yml file ... )

```
         "Config": {
                "Hostname": "5337012111a5",
                "Domainname": "",
                "User": "",
                "AttachStdin": false,
                "AttachStdout": false,
                "AttachStderr": false,
                "PortSpecs": null,
                "ExposedPorts": {
                    "5000/tcp": {}
                },
                "Tty": false,
                "OpenStdin": false,
                "StdinOnce": false,
                "Env": [
                    "SETTINGS_FLAVOR=local",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECURE=True",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ENCRYPT=True",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ROOTDIRECTORY=/s3/object/name/prefix",
                    "CACHE_REDIS_PORT=6379",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_V4AUTH=True",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_CHUNKSIZE=5242880",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy”,
                    "CACHE_LRU_REDIS_PORT=6379",
                    "SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy",
                    "CACHE_REDIS_HOST=cache",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”,
                    "CACHE_LRU_REDIS_HOST=cache",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION=eu-central-1",
                    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=harbor.dufour16.net",
                    "PATH=/go/bin:/usr/src/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                    "GOLANG_VERSION=1.4.2",
                    "GOPATH=/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution/Godeps/_workspace:/go",
                    "DISTRIBUTION_DIR=/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution"
                ],
                "Cmd": [
                    "cmd/registry/config.yml"
                ],
                "Image": "registry:2",
                "Volumes": null,
                "VolumeDriver": "",
                "WorkingDir": "/go/src/github.com/docker/distribution",
                "Entrypoint": [
                    "registry"
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to override settings with environment variables.. not using external volumes ..